# Hibernate OGM: How to store a List<Double>?

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

Is it possible to store List with Hibernate OGM and mongodb without creating a Entity for type Double.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class Series extends Default {
    private List<Double> results;
```

Gives the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Series, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(results)]
```

If I add a @OneToMany relation to the List I have to create a Entity for Double otherwise it will throw:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class
```

Comment: How do you expect to store an unfixed-size list of doubles in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the annotation `@ElementCollection`.

Like this:

```
@ElementCollection
private List<Double> results;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [UserType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) to convert your `List<Double>` to a `String`, but you will lose the availability to use aggregates functions over this field.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, per docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.0 it seems that the collection should be initialized as mentioned by @Zircon